# Nine lemma for fibration sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration

I am wondering if there is an analogue of the nine lemma for fibration sequences of spaces. The situation I am in is that I have the following diagram:

[image]

All the columns and the first 2 rows are fibration sequences. Is the 3rd row necessarily a fibration sequence? (possibly assuming that the composition is already nullhomotopic). I'm pretty sure this is true if we work in the stable homotopy category since we can use some version of the nine lemma for triangulated categories, but is it true just for topological spaces? (or possibly even just CW complexes?)

Comment: Can you set $F=F'=X=X'=Y=Y'=*$ and $A=B=C=S^1$ with the map $B \to C$ being the identity? Then everything apart from the third row is a fibration and all squares commute, but the third row is not a fibration. Not sure if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @jasnee Hmm maybe there is some simple counter example which I can't think of. I don't think that works though because then the columns ($ * \to * \to S^1$) wouldn't be a fibration sequence as the homotopy fibre of $* \to S^1$ would be $\Omega S^1$. I could be mistaken though

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense, I missed that!